# Program hardcodes an API port to localhost, how to expose it to network?

Tags: networking, router, apache-http-server, port-forwarding, localhost

I'm running a program that exposes a TCP-JSON messaging system bound to 127.0.0.1:4000. The IP and the port are non-negotiable and cannot be changed in configuration files; any attempt to rebind (which is theoretically supported) to the LAN IP (192.168.x.x for example) causes the program to fail, since it's constantly looking for 127.0.0.1:4000.

Even when binding it to port 4000 on the LAN IP, it fails.

What's the best way to work around this situation? I want to make the port accessible over the network, and I've done this for the MySQL and apache servers running on the machine. But this port is stubborn since it binds to localhost.

Is there anyway to point the LAN IP at it for that given port? I've tried redirecting localhost in the hosts ifle to it, but that fails (as expected). Not sure if there's anything in `netsh` that can be run for this. Google searching and checking StackOverflow/SuperUser have been unsuccessful, as they all describe situations where the port is bound to the LAN IP, not localhost.

Thanks.

**EDIT: It's running Windows 10.**

Comment: You mention `/etc/hosts` like in Linux and `netsh` like in Windows. What OS then? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Apologies - it's Windows. Edited.